# Single Quoted String Over Multiple Lines

Tags: php, string, multiline

I am working through this PHP & MySQL book and I have run into something quite different than what I am used to when it comes to echoing multiple lines of a single quoted string.

The example given is this:

```
    echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="75%">
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><b>This</b></td>
          <td align="left"><b>That</b></td>
          <td align="left"><b>Then</b></td>
          <td align="left"><b>When</b></td>
          <td align="left"><b>What</b></td>
        </tr>';
```

Obviously I could break out of PHP and use HTML, but this isn't always an option. And when I don't have that option I would usually break up my string for easier reading as such:

```
    echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="75%">' . 
      '<tr>'
        '<td align="left"><b>This</b></td>' . 
        '<td align="left"><b>That</b></td>' . 
        '<td align="left"><b>Then</b></td>' . 
        '<td align="left"><b>When</b></td>' . 
        '<td align="left"><b>What</b></td>' . 
      '</tr>';
```

The author of this book is well respected in the php community, and the book comes highly recommended and is reviewed well... So my question is this:

Is There anything wrong with his method and should this be practiced?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with it, but consider using [`heredoc syntax`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for multi-line strings.

Comment: Why is the second version easier to read than the first? I'd say the opposite, with all the added punctuation in there...

Comment: The second way was the original way I learned to echo out multi-line strings. It gave me warm fuzzies to know there were no extra spaces or tabs. But as you can see, I could easily mess up: Missing a dot on line 2.

Comment: If you look at performance only, it is a bit faster to output HTML without additional whitespace, but maybe the author does it in that way because he wishes to output HTML that is also readable to humans :-) Also, all those string concatenations increase the overhead just a little bit.

Comment: "Obviously I could break out of PHP and use HTML, but this isn't always an option." - Incorrect.  When it comes to outputting text, that is -always- an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong with it at all. Just be aware that the spaces, tabs and line returns in the quoted string will be output as well. That's rarely a problem - just something to remember.

To me, it's a little easier to read and a little harder to get wrong than your way. In fact, your example has a syntax error. Can you find the missing dot?

Comment: This feature is there in netbeans. If you are typing a string and you press return, the current line is closed with quote and new line is concatinated.

Answer (score 5):

There are even more possibilities

```
?>
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="75%">
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><b>This</b></td>
      <td align="left"><b>That</b></td>
      <td align="left"><b>Then</b></td>
      <td align="left"><b>When</b></td>
      <td align="left"><b>What</b></td>
    </tr>
<?php
```

or

```
echo <<<HTML
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="75%">
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><b>This</b></td>
      <td align="left"><b>That</b></td>
      <td align="left"><b>Then</b></td>
      <td align="left"><b>When</b></td>
      <td align="left"><b>What</b></td>
    </tr>
HTML;
```

The first one is recognized as HTML in every IDE, the second one at least in PHPStorm, and thus IDEs can highlight it using the HTML-syntax-highlighting, which is a *huge* benefit compared to your *both* examples (Sidenote: PHPStorm highlights html in strings too, thus it's not that bad ;) But as far as I remember it cannot validate html in strings)

Additional you should separate output- from processing-code

Comment: Your first one is what I meant by breaking out of php

Comment: ah, ok, I see. If you separate the view- from the application-layer (one may call that "templating"), than this is _always_ an option :)